# Cant create financial account using personal banker profile user?

Tags: financial-services-cloud

I have installed a package in Financial Service Cloud, I have enabled the personal banker profile created User. Whenever I try to create a financial account of Ownership "individual" I get this error:

> FinServ.FinancialAccountRoleTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: FinServ.MoiExceptionWrapper.TriggerException: Something's not quite right. Try your action again, and if the issue continues, contact your administrator for help. (FinServ)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This exception can be thrown when person accounts are in use but not configured properly. Follow the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_enable_person_acct.htm) and pay particular attention to the notes that are highlighted on naming.

Comment: I followed The same process , and the issue is only coming for personal banker profile User and also I could Create The financial account when Ownership is joint,but Then Rollups does not work and all rollup Show 0 even though i am entering The Balance.While the whole Process work fine For System admin rollups and all.Thanks

Comment: In Personal banker profile somehow field level security got overwritten after changing them it worked thanks anyway.